# Re-use if statement for all click handler events in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a few click handler events on my page that simply add an active class to an element. I only want the event to trigger if the current section has the class active. I have this working ok but what I am doing is running the same for loop and if statement check for the active class on my section for the different click events. Looking for the simplest way to re-use it using just javascript not jquery.

```
<section class="section section-1 active">
  <div class="button">
    <div class="hidden-background"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-content"></div>
</section>

<section class="section section-2">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="hidden-background"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-content"></div>
  </section>

  <section class="section section-3">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="hidden-background"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden-content"></div>
    </section>
```

The button click event checks for the active section and just finds the first div tag (hidden-background) and applies an active class to it.

```
var section = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
var button = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

for (var s = 0; s < section.length; s++) {
    if (section[s].classList.contains('active')) {
        for (var b = 0; b < button.length; b++) {
            button[b].addEventListener('click', function(){
                this.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].classList.add('active');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The second click event again checks for the active section class and then adds the class active to the hidden-content div.

```
var section = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
var hiddenContent = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden-content');

for (var s = 0; s < section.length; s++) {
    if (section[s].classList.contains('active')) {
        for (var h = 0; h < hiddenContent.length; h++) {
            hiddenContent[h].addEventListener('click', function(){
                this.classList.add('active');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `for (var h = 0; h < button.length; h++) {` Is that a typo?

Comment: literally just saw that myself and amended. It was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
const makeActive = function(evt) {
  evt.target.parentElement
    .querySelectorAll('.hidden-background, .hidden-content')
    .forEach( el => el.classList.add('active'));
};

document
  .querySelectorAll('.section.active .button')
  .forEach( btn => btn.addEventListener('click', makeActive) );
```

And assuming the active sections also are toggled by javascript. (The above would no longer work if someone changed the active section, since the eventListener is still bound to the old section)

```
const makeActive = function(evt) {
  if(
    evt.target.className.contains('button') && 
    evt.target.parentElement.className.contains('active')
  ){
    evt.target.parentElement
      .querySelectorAll('.hidden-background, .hidden-content')
      .forEach( el => el.classList.add('active'));
  }
};

document
  .querySelectorAll('.section')
  .forEach( section => section.addEventListener('click', makeActive) );
```

Of course, this whole thing would be easier with only css:

```
.hidden-background, .hidden-content { display: none; }
.active .hidden-background, .active .hidden-content { display: block; }
```

but I suppose that is a different question altogether...